# Angular2 testing with Jasmine, beforeEach is run twice

Tags: angular, jasmine

I'm using Angular2 with Jasmine/Karma for testing, pretty standard A2-installation.

In my `app.component.spec.ts` file I have the following code:

```
let str;
describe('1st tests', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    str = 'potato';
    console.log('TEST LOG'); // This is shown twice in the terminal
  });

  it('should equal potato', () => {
    expect(str).toEqual('potato');
  });

});
```

The test runs and is passed but it seems like the code inside `beforeEach()` is run twice. In this simple example that doesn't cause any problems but as soon as I try to use `TestBed` to instantiate components etc I get major errors.

Why is the code inside `beforeEach()` run twice?

**edit: posting my karma.conf.js** below:

```
var path = require('path');

var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config');

module.exports = function (config) {
  var _config = {

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',

    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      { pattern: './karma-shim.js', watched: false }
    ],

    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [],

    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
      './karma-shim.js': ['webpack', 'sourcemap']
    },

    webpack: webpackConfig,

    webpackMiddleware: {
      // webpack-dev-middleware configuration
      // i. e.
      stats: 'errors-only'
    },

    coverageReporter: {
      dir: 'coverage/',
      reporters: [{
        type: 'json',
        dir: 'coverage',
        subdir: 'json',
        file: 'coverage-final.json'
      }]
    },

    remapIstanbulReporter: {
      src: 'coverage/json/coverage-final.json',
      reports: {
        lcovonly: 'coverage/json/lcov.info',
        html: 'coverage/html',
        'text': null
      },
      timeoutNotCreated: 1000, // default value
      timeoutNoMoreFiles: 1000 // default value
    },

    webpackServer: {
      noInfo: true // please don't spam the console when running in karma!
    },

    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress', 'mocha'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ["mocha", "coverage", "karma-remap-istanbul"],

    // web server port
    port: 9876,

    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,

    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: false,

    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'], // you can also use Chrome

    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: true
  };

  config.set(_config);

};
```

Comment: what's your karma config file?

Comment: added it to my post